# Can't Access uploaded image via Spring MVC Web Application in the HTML

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing Spring MVC web application. Here I use multipart form to upload image to user folder in resources folder of my-application-folder in wtpwebapp folder in Tomcat home. I successfully uploaded image. at anytime I can't show these images in HTML pages. also resourceHandlers add into configuration, but not working

### file upload logic

```java
if(!file.isEmpty()) {
    String relativeWebPath = "/resources/users";
    String absoluteFilePath = context.getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
    String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
    Path uploadPath = Paths.get(absoluteFilePath);
                
    if (!Files.exists(uploadPath)) {
        Files.createDirectories(uploadPath);
    }
                
    try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream()) {
        Path filePath = uploadPath.resolve(fileName);
        System.out.println("filePath-"+filePath.toFile().getAbsolutePath());
        Files.copy(inputStream, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {        
        throw new IOException("Could not save image file: " + fileName, ioe);
    } 
}
```

### WebMVCConfiguration

```java
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        
       registry.addResourceHandler("/user/**")
        .addResourceLocations("file:${catalina.home}/wtpwebapps/city-taxi-     application/resources/users/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/views/css/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/views/css/");
        
        registry.addResourceHandler("/views/lib/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/views/lib/");
        
        registry.addResourceHandler("/views/js/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/views/js/");
        
        registry.addResourceHandler("/views/img/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/views/img/");
        
        System.out.println("Resource Handler Configuration:");
        System.out.println("URL Pattern: " + urlPattern);
        System.out.println("Resource Location: " + resourceLocation);
        
    }
```

### HTML

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-xl-12" style="text-align:center;padding- top:30px;padding-bottom:30px;">

          <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/advocate.png" alt="Uploaded Image"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried different ways. but I couldn't do it.

Comment: when you enable access log what do you see as error for the requested image ?